# SPTraceV4 service is using a built in account

Tags: logging

So, after a clean install of SharePoint 2010 you sometimes get a warning that a service is using a built in account. This is found in yellow in the Monitoring panel in Central Administration.

Upon further examinination, the service at fault is SPTraceV4 (though the actual error on the console (rather than the error detail) is SPTimerServiceV4 is failing).

Sure enough, upon checking the windows services console, the account for SPTraceV4 is the built in local service account.

So, is there a proper way to update this account to something other than local service OR to prohibit its provisioning with a local service account? Is this a bug?

Another thread with similiar detail is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/0e89487d-5b1e-46ba-9956-f04ebcf8646c

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get rid of this somebody posted this [complicated PowerShell script](http://blog.isaacblum.com/2011/02/21/built-in-accounts-are-used-as-application-pool-or-service-identities/) to fix it.

My personal view is that it seems like a lot of effort. I suspect it will be fixed in the next version, anyway. I am lazy and just disable the health rule. Sorry.